# How to display most recent value in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have trouble accessing the last value (row) of my CSV to display it on hover in my line chart. I need the value to be displayed as text, but also to be used as Y coordinate to line up with the end of the line.
This is what I have. The first part works, but not the second (in between ///):

```
function mouseover(d) {
d3.select(d.corporation.line).classed("corporation--hover", true);
d.corporation.line.parentNode.appendChild(d.corporation.line);
focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
focus.select(".corpname").text(d.corporation.name);
focus.select(".ranking").text(d.value);
/////
focus.append("text")
.datum(function(d) { return {name: d.corporation.name, value: d.corporation.value[d.corporation.values.length - 1]}; })
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.values) + ")"; })
.text(function(d) { return d.value; });
/////
}
```

I tried few different variations without success. Would love if someone could take a peak.

PLUNK is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Nf992jYjSGyKhLhaij5?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have conflicting d value. The one you pass to the mouseover : mouseover(d), and the one you use elsewhere, for example, .datum(function(d){ ... its unclear what value you wish to use but maybe this is your problem

Comment: I am completely lost about the way to do that. I tried to start from scratch, and clean up things, but as of right now I am only able to display the hover value, and I cannot pick up the last (most recent) value I want to display at the end of the line. If anyone has time, I would love to understand how to make it work.
Here's a clean plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv47CGKKTQVmvxttj4Mc?p=preview
thanks!

Comment: @CapivaraGraphics By last recent value can you let us know which record from csv.

Comment: @SiddP Yes, that would be the 2016 column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you access the data bound to your line element: `this.__data__`

First, let's create a variable to access your data, specifically the array of values:

```
var that = this.__data__.corporation.values;
```

Then, we can get the date and the value of the end of the line:

```
var thatLength = that.length;
var thatValue = that[thatLength - 1].value;
var thatDate = that[thatLength - 1].date;
```

And display the text:

```
someLegend
.attr("x", (x(yearFormat(thatDate))*-1)-90)
.attr("y", y(thatValue))
.text(thatValue);
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4HquzuJ6FJeZvEVWuUS5?p=preview

PS: I created this variable `someLegend` because I didn't have time to understand the `translate` logic of your `focus`.

Comment: No worries, @CapivaraGraphics. The most important is that now you have `thatValue` for the value and `thatDate` for the date. Playing with `this.__data__` you can retrieve any data bound to the element. Try `console.log(this.__data__);` and you'll see.